# Calling private function within package body

Tags: oracle, plsql

According to Oracle documentation one can make items private in packages by declaring them in the body but not in the specification.

I have a procedure in this package that needs to call a function that should not be accessed outside of this package. Oracle SQL Developer returns `PLS-00313 'ADD_STUDENT' not declared in this scope`

Declaration:

```
PACKAGE SCHOOL AS
    PROCEDURE ADD_PEOPLE(...);
END SCHOOL;
```

Body:

```
PACKAGE BODY SCHOOL AS
    PROCEDURE ADD_PEOPLE(...)
        ...
        ADD_STUDENT();
    END ADD_PEOPLE;

    FUNCTION ADD_STUDENT(...)
        ...
    END ADD_STUDENT;
END SCHOOL;
```

I can't find an example of calling internal functions/procedures and whether the package declaration is needed ex:`SCHOOL.ADD_STUDENT()`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue you have (assuming that you are calling the correctly named procedure/function in the correct manner) is that you are trying to invoke a call to a function that hasn't yet been declared. There are two ways around this, assuming you want to keep the function private:

1. Declare the ADD_STUDENT function before any procedures/functions that invoke it.
2. Use [forward declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#LNPLS99896) to declare the function before it is invoked.

So, for option 1, your example code would look like:

```
PACKAGE BODY SCHOOL AS
    FUNCTION ADD_STUDENT(...)
        ...
    END ADD_STUDENT;

    PROCEDURE ADD_PEOPLE(...)
        ...
        some_var := ADD_STUDENT();
    END ADD_PEOPLE;
END SCHOOL;
/
```

And for option 2 your code would look like:

```
PACKAGE BODY SCHOOL AS
    -- forward declared function
    FUNCTION ADD_STUDENT(...);

    PROCEDURE ADD_PEOPLE(...)
        ...
        some_var := ADD_STUDENT();
    END ADD_PEOPLE;

    FUNCTION ADD_STUDENT(...)
        ...
    END ADD_STUDENT;
END SCHOOL;
/
```

Personally, I favour option 1, as it means there's less stuff cluttering up the package body, but option 2 might be necessary if you have two modules that reference each other.

Comment: Great answer, didn't realize package body is loaded sequentially. Small extension on this then: Do you know if there would be a performance improvement having most often called public functions and procedures at the top of the package?

Comment: I would have thought that was unlikely; I believe the compiler converts the code into something more streamlined, so what you see when you look at a the package body's text is not necessarily what the database code sees.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the private function before it is referenced in the body.

Simply define the function and then the procedure.

The package declaration is not needed - just call it with the name in the body as that name is already in scope.

Comment: Just to clarify; adding it to the package declaration would make it public and thus invalidating this use-case.

Comment: @Thor - Not suggesting adding it to the package header. Was simply saying that in the body the PRIVATE function needs defining before it is referenced.

Answer (score 0):

In Package Specification your are defining function as ADD_STUDENT
While you are calling  ADD_STUDENTS();

Please remove 'S' and compile it again.

Comment: Done, still same problem. Editing question to avoid confusion.

Comment: Please refer this -https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/packages.htm#LNPLS00913 Here 'sal_ok' is local function